# Legend for plot of multiple functions involving ReplaceAll only shows first function

Tags: plotting, legending

In Mathematica 13.2, while defining a function for manipulating and animating a plot of multiple functions, I'm unable to generate a legend for the second and subsequent functions in my list. I've narrowed down the problem to the use of `ReplaceAll`(`/.`).

Here is a simplified demo:

1. The first `Plot[]` does not contain a `/.` and behaves correctly: Each function gets its own color and legend.
2. The second `Plot[]` contains a `/.` and plots all functions with the same color and only the first function gets a legend.
3. The third `Plot[]` adds an `Evaluated -> True` directive, which fixes the color but not the legend issue.

`Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"n=1", "n=2", "n=3"}]`

`Plot[{x, x^2, x^3} /. {}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"n=1", "n=2", "n=3"}]`

`Plot[{x, x^2, x^3} /. {}, {x, -1, 1}, Evaluated -> True, PlotLegends -> {"n=1", "n=2", "n=3"}]`

[image: Mathematica plots of the functions x, x^2, and x^3, exhibiting incorrect coloration and legends]

In my actual code, I make use of the `ReplaceAll` directive to expose parameters to `Manipulate[]` so I'd like to learn how to get legends to work with `/.`.

I'm new to Mathematica and, from what I could tell after extensive searching on MMA.SE, the `Evaluate -> True` directive *ought* to have been enough to get `Plot[]` to treat its input as a true list and map each list item to a separate legend text. Clearly I'm missing some nuance. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Plot[Evaluate[({x, x^2, x^3} /. {})], {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"n=1", "n=2", "n=3"}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Brilliant! I was previously trying to wrap `Evaluate[]` around the function list itself but it makes sense why it should be wrapped around the `ReplaceAll` instead. Thank you!